# how does spfx get builded? how to build custom spfx generator

Tags: spfx

I am learning spfx webpart. I open the gulpfile.js file but it only has limited code lines. how can I know the procedure of building spfx webpart?

And I notice that there is a PNP spfx generator. is it possible to create my own custom spfx generator? or involve spfx into my node project?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

SPFx projects are built using a complex Build System that is an npm package. You can find it under node_modules folder under the name - @microsoft/sp-build-web

This package makes use of more packages. You can go into the node_moduels folder and look for packages named @microsoft/gulp-core-build*

The entire build system is built in Object oriented code with lots of classes and interfaces using TypeScript.

If you want to just customize the Build process then you can build custom tasks which are coded in the gulpfile.js.

On good article to learn is at - https://rencore.com/blog/extending-sharepoint-framework-build-process-custom-tasks/

Comment: oh seems you're right. i find it very complex. i just want to learn something about how this project was built. extend my skill. this doc you provided is helpful! 